# Debug Phoenix framework through Elixir in VSCode, NMAKE error

Tags: debugging, elixir, phoenix-framework, nmake

I am trying to debug my elixir code in Phoenix framework in Visual Studio Code. The code uses `comeonin` and `argon` (which in turn needs NMAKE) for authorization purposes which is mentioned in one of the `mix.exs` file as below:

`{:elixir_make, "~> 0.4.2"},
 {:comeonin, "~> 4.1.1"},
 {:argon2_elixir, "~> 1.3.3"},`

Initially when I was running the server from normal command prompt, I was getting the below mentioned error, **which got subsequently resolved after I performed the suggested steps mentioned in the error itself**.

> an exception was raised:
>       ** (Mix.Error) Could not compile with "nmake" (exit status: 2).
>   One option is to install a recent version of
>   [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)
>   either manually or using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) -
>   "choco install VisualCppBuildTools".
>
> After installing Visual C++ Build Tools, look in the "Program Files (x86)"
>   directory and search for "Microsoft Visual Studio". Note down the full path
>   of the folder with the highest version number. Open the "run" command and
>   type in the following command (make sure that the path and version number
>   are correct):

```
cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

>
This should open up a command prompt with the necessary environment variables
set, and from which you will be able to run the "mix compile", "mix deps.compile",and "mix test" commands.

```
    (mix) lib/mix.ex:323: Mix.raise/1
    lib/mix/tasks/compile.make.ex:100: Mix.Tasks.Compile.ElixirMake.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:316: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:68: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run_compiler/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:52: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.do_compile/4
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:23: anonymous fn/1 in Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:39: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.with_logger_app/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:316: Mix.Task.run_task/3
```

Now, when I am trying to run the code from Visual Studio Code - I am getting the same error again, though it was resolved earlier while running through console. Redoing the same thing not solving the issue. Where can I go wrong ? Is it the correct way to debug in VSCode?

Comment: Did you start VS Code from the console with the loaded environment?

Comment: Yes I did that as well, but getting the same error. Wondering how VScode not recognizing NMAKE whereas normal command prompt is able to do that. Is VSCode not considering some of the environmental variables while running in itself?

Comment: As long as the `mix` command options in your `vscode/task.json` does not specify an `env` property `mix` should inherit the environment of the parent process, which in turn should contain the variables from `vcvarsall.bat` if you've started VS Code from the console with the loaded environment.

Comment: I am not sure if I need to append anything in the launch.json file in VSCODE. currently it is the default one that VSCode generates.